# How do you dynamically Assing Unique Code for every row iin hierarchical table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My table.

Table1

```
Id  ParentId Name   Code
1   Null     John  
2   1        Harry
3   1        Mary
4   2        Emma
5   2        Kyle
6   4        Robert
7   Null     Rohit
```

I want to assign each individual with the the following format unique hierarchy codes

Output Required

```
 Id   ParentId   Name      Code
    1   Null     John     1
    2   1        Harry    1.1
    3   1        Mary     1.2
    4   2        Emma     1.1.1
    5   2        Kyle     1.1.2
    6   4        Robert   1.1.1.1
    7  Null      Rohit    2
```

and so on.

Comment: This was closed as duplicate, but the linked question did not cover the creation of a "unique code" for every row depending on an incrementing number. So I decided to re-open the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've got this correctly...

You can use a recursive CTE together with `ROW_NUMBER()` in order to create your codes.

```
DECLARE @dummy TABLE(Id INT,ParentId INT,[Name] VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @dummy(Id,ParentId,[Name]) VALUES
 (1,Null,'John')  
,(2,1   ,'Harry')
,(3,1   ,'Mary')
,(4,2   ,'Emma')
,(5,2   ,'Kyle')
,(6,4   ,'Robert')
,(7,Null,'Rohit');

WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT Id,ParentId,[Name]
          ,CONCAT(N'.',CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) AS Code 
    FROM @dummy WHERE ParentId IS NULL

    UNION ALL
    SELECT d.Id,d.ParentId,d.[Name]
          ,CONCAT(r.Code,N'.', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.Id)) 
    FROM @dummy d
    INNER JOIN recCTE r ON d.ParentId=r.Id
)
SELECT Id,ParentId,[Name] 
      ,STUFF(Code,1,1,'') AS Code
FROM RecCTE;
```

The idea in short:

We pick the rows with `ParentId IS NULL` and give them a running number.
Now we go iteratively through them (it's a *hidden RBAR* actually) and call their children, again with a running number.
This we do until there is nothing left.
the final `SELECT` needs a `STUFF` in order to to get rid of the first dot.

And with an extension like this, you can create an alphanumerically sortable code:

```
WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT Id,ParentId,[Name]
          ,CONCAT(N'.',CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) AS Code 
          ,CONCAT(N'000',CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) AS Code2 
    FROM @dummy WHERE ParentId IS NULL

    UNION ALL
    SELECT d.Id,d.ParentId,d.[Name]
          ,CONCAT(r.Code,N'.', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.Id)) 
          ,CONCAT(r.Code2,RIGHT(CONCAT('0000',ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.Id)),4))
    FROM @dummy d
    INNER JOIN recCTE r ON d.ParentId=r.Id
)
SELECT Id,ParentId,[Name] 
      ,STUFF(Code,1,1,'') AS Code
      ,Code2
FROM RecCTE
ORDER BY Code2;
```